# Composer Download Error

Tags: composer-php

i got this error when i'm trying to install composer for laravel framework :

"Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:
The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl"

i tried much but i don't know what should i do right now ?

i got win 8.1 , wamp 1.7 , php 5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open *C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini & C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini*

Find the line `;extension=php_openssl.dll` and remove the semicolons ';'.

The line should look like `extension=php_openssl.dll`.

Comment: Could you please explain your actions shortly?

Comment: I did that , i deleted the ; before the line you told me , but i had the same error which i got , it didn't work.